# How to bacon infuse solid cheese block for smoking?

Tags: cheese, smoking, bacon

I already cold smoke cheese. I'm looking to add bacon flavor to that cheese. Would soaking it in cooked bacon grease and cutting off the heavily saturated outer section work?

Comment: How would you define "bacon flavor"?  What should it get you that smoke does not?

Comment: A lot of bacon's flavoring is in the smoke. You have to be careful for the bacon not to overrun the cheese flavor.

Comment: I suspect if you cut off the outside, you would find that the rest of the cheese would have very little of the bacon flavour - fats and flavour compounds within the fat will permeate very little into the block of cheese.

Comment: Not really an answer therefore comment :) if you like to baconize so much your cheese, consider cutting it in little or mid pieces, and then roll them in bacon slice. This is often done here with salumi and soft cheese, but something more rustic can be interesting too (I suppose your cheese to be semi hard). I am sure you can also make cubes for tasty appetizers

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, sorry for the delay in response, I've been trying to figure out how to better phrase what I'm trying to achieve. I've had "bacon infused cheddar" before, but it was at one of those tourist traps with "gourmet" food. EZ Cheese makes a product, a cheddar bacon, I want to infuse bacon into the cheese to that degree. Without, who knows what's in EZ Cheese.

Comment: I want some of the pork flavor in the cheese.

Answer (score 1):

Part of it depends on how you use the cheese.

To get a bacon-infused cheese block, the best and easiest way would be to buy some cheddar culture and make your own - the bacon fat, or even crumbles, well dried, can be added during the process, layered between curds, etc.  The block can be aged and/or smoked after pressing.

It may, maybe, be possible to take a block of cheddar, shred or chunk it, toss in some grease and/or crumbles, and press it into another block.  You would need to start with a young cheddar, and give a great deal of time and/or pressure to re-combine the cheese - seems like a lot of work for little return, and it saves very little work over making from scratch.

Soaking the cheese block in the grease, or adding a layer of such onto it after smoking and before storage, would get flavor into the outermost edges (it would not likely infuse far without extensive time).  Cutting those edges off would readily undo most of the flavor addition, though.  That saturated section you're concerned about, though, would not necessarily be a large part of any portion - it would be mainly be around the rind of a slice (small surface area) or mixed into a shredded pile... though additional cheddar can be added if the smoking on top of grease is still too much flavor.

The only other alternative I can think of would be keeping the bacon flavor on hand (as grease, or as commercial seasonings or flavorings) to add to the cheese at the time of use.

Answer (score 0):

I would try coating the cheese (I also assume you are working with semi-hard cheese) with bacon grease, making sure to cut the cheese into smaller(2-3lb blocks) and letting it 'marinade' for 12 to twenty four hours. I would then wrap the cheese with bacon before smoking, if you are going to be using the cheese in the shredded form, you could try shredding it first, mixing in some bacon grease and bacon bits, then cold smoking it. Hope this helps.